# In golang os.OpenFile doesn't return os.ErrNotExist if file does not exist

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm trying to open a file and I'd like to know if it doesn't exist to react. But the error

```
os.OpenFile(fName, os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
```

returns when the file does not exist is different than os.ErrNotExists

```
os.ErrNotExists -> "file does not exist"
err.(*os.PathError).Err -> "no such file or directory"
```

os.Stat also return the same error if the file is not there. Is there a predefined error I can compare to instead of having to do it by hand?

Answer (score 25):

> [Package os](https://golang.org/pkg/os/)
>
> [func IsExist](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsExist)
>
> ```
> func IsExist(err error) bool
> ```
>
> IsExist returns a boolean indicating whether the error is known to
>   report that a file or directory already exists. It is satisfied by
>   ErrExist as well as some syscall errors.
>
> [func IsNotExist](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsNotExist)
>
> ```
> func IsNotExist(err error) bool
> ```
>
> IsNotExist returns a boolean indicating whether the error is known to
>   report that a file or directory does not exist. It is satisfied by
>   ErrNotExist as well as some syscall errors.

Use the `os.IsNotExist` function. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fname := "No File"
    _, err := os.OpenFile(fname, os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            fmt.Print("File Does Not Exist: ")
        }
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
File Does Not Exist: open No File: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

Originally posted as an anonymous suggested edit to the other answer:

As of Go 1.17, the preferred way to check for this error is:

```golang
errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist)
```

[Source](https://golang.google.cn/pkg/os/#IsNotExist)